# Inserting data using for each loop and ignoring text fields that have no data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 text fields that insert into a single table

**HTML**

```
<table width="200" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="textfield">Van Number:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="van[]" id="textfield" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="textfield2">Van Number:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="van[]" id="textfield2" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my insert function for mysql

**MYSQL PHP**

```
    foreach ($_POST['van'] as $van) {
        mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
        $sql = ("INSERT INTO tbl_van (van_number, tbl_delivery_details_id_delivery_details)     VALUES('$van', '$id_delivery')");
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect)){ 
            die('Error: '. mysql_error()); 
        } 

    }
}

?>
```

I made it 2 text fields because usually there is 2 van numbers needed to be inserted, but sometimes there will be 3 and 4 van numbers. I have a problem with 3 van numbers because it will insert the empty field into the database and the next time i add 3 again it will be empty again for the other text field and the third wont get inserted because there is already a blank data in the database and it wont add the same blank value because it is not unique anymore. I want to be able to insert data and ignore the blank field and insert only the text field that has data and that is not blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect); // take this outside the loop
foreach ($_POST['van'] as $van) {
    $van = trim($van);
    if ($van != '') {
        $sql = ("INSERT INTO tbl_van (van_number, tbl_delivery_details_id_delivery_details)     VALUES('$van', '$id_delivery')");
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect)){ 
            die('Error: '. mysql_error()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to ignore the blank field?

Comment: @user3282248: The statement `if ($van != '') {` is to check whether the field is blank, and if yes, ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please look into PDO and SQL injection (parameter binding) because this is your textbook worst approach on inserting user provided data into your database.

Second, read up on database normalization. The problem you're having here is due to a database design flaw.

Create a van table with singular van data, and create a van number table for all numbers associated to this van.

Comment: i have this $van = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['van']); i didnt include on my post

Comment: Sadly that's still far from good enough, the mysql library is deprecated (see http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php) and for good reason: it's very unsafe compared to using bound parameters with prepared statements.

Your scenario still screams 'bad database design'. If you have a variable amount of van numbers, put them in a different table and use a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

giv the input text different name:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="textfield2" />
<input type="text" name="name2" id="textfield2" />
```

you can then play with PHP code as you like.

Comment: you have an idea on how to ignore a blank text field?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Have not tested it just checking around :) Don't forget to do proper value checking and escaping.. :)

```
$values = array();
foreach($_POST['van'] as $van) {
        if( ! trim($van)) continue;
        $values[] = '(' . $number . ', ' . $id_delivery . ')';
}
if($values) {
        mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);    
        $query = 'INSERT INTO tbl_van (van_number, tbl_delivery_details_id_delivery_details) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $values);
        mysql_query($query, $connect);
}
```